# How to format numbers on tooltips with ZingChart

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I would like to format the number that's displayed on a tooltip like this:

```
var num = 0.1234567890;
num.toFixed(4);
"0.1235"
```

I checked the [documentation](http://[https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/design-and-styling/formatting-numbers/#data__formatting][1]) but it mostly deals with dates and big numbers

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZingChart has a `decimals` attribute that can format numbers on a global scale across the plot. What this means is if you apply the `decimals` attribute within plot the `valueBox` will inherit this property and `tooltip` will as well.

```
 plot: {
  decimals: 4,
  valueBox: {

  }
}...
```

If you do this just within the tooltip object you will only get the truncated value applied to the tooltip.

**Note: the underscore in front of a JSON attribute is like an inline comment.**

[plot docs here](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/#zcdemo)

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: 'bar', 
  plot: {
    _decimals: 4,
    valueBox: {}
  },
  tooltip: {
    decimals: 4
  },
 series: [
  {
   values: [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```